# Python: Can't access Instance Variable inside Class function

Tags: python, class, variables, object

When trying to access the instance variable `self.density` in `select_object` from within the `populate_grid` method of `class Map`, I get `AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'density'`.

However, accessing `self.density` from `select_object` alone works fine.
Could someone please explain what I'm not seeing?

```
# Handles player and scene locations
from random import randint, choice


class Map(object):
    def __init__(self, size, objects, density=0.05):
        self.size = size
        self.objects = objects
        self.grid = self.populate_grid(size)
        self.density = density

    def populate_grid(self, size):
        grid = {}
        for i in range(size):
            y = 0
            for j in range(size):
                grid[C(i, y)] = self.select_object()
                y += 1

        return grid

    def select_object(self):
        if randint(0, 100) < (self.density*100):
            print('yes')
            return choice(self.objects)
        else:
            return 0


random_objects = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

s = Map(4, random_objects, 0.5)

s.select_object()
```

Complete code is available here: http://pastebin.com/TxLMSbH0

Comment: Please post an MCVE. Most of your code looks irrelevant.

Comment: Condensed it down for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you call `self.grid = self.populate_grid(size)` *before* initializing self.density. So when populate_grid gets executed, `self.density` is not set.

The solution would be to move `self.density = density` above that call.

Comment: Thank you, did not realize the significance of placing the `populate_grid` call before the `self.density` declaration :)